# c- pthreads: pthread_create fail with error code 11(EAGAIN)

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

We have a set up in which we are recording video to SD card continuously using our custom board. But we are facing an issue with `pthread_create` in the long run.

I got an `EAGAIN` when trying to spawn a thread using pthread_create. However, from what I've checked, the threads seem to have been terminated properly.

Would it be possible that unclosed file handles play a part in causing this `EAGAIN` (i.e they share the same resource space)?

I tried with the attribute `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED`. Here is my code snippet.

```
int alarm_main_loop(int qid, int audQid, SemHandl_t hAlarmSem)
{
    ALARM_MSG_BUF msgbuf;
    int msg_size, ret = 0;
    int event_index, sch_index;
    AlarmParam_t* pEvironment;
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    pAlarmSysInfo = GetSysInfo();
    if((hGIOSem = MakeSem()) == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    /* ADDED TO SEND SCHEDULE INFO TO SCHEDULE MANAGER */
    for (event_index = 0; event_index < MAX_NO_OF_EVENTS; event_index++) {
        for (sch_index = 0; sch_index < MAX_SCHEDULES; sch_index++) {
            Set_Event_Schedule(pAlarmSysInfo>event_details[event_index].event_schedule[sch_index], event_index, sch_index, 0);
        }
    }
    while(1)
    {
        /* Get Message */
        msg_size = msgrcv( qid, &msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf) - sizeof(long), MSG_TYPE_MSG1, 0);
        if( msg_size < 0 ){
            printf("Alarm Receive msg fail \n");
            ret = -1;
            break;
        } else if(msgbuf.src == MSG_TYPE_MSG1 || msgbuf.src < 0){
            printf("Got Error message\n");
            ret = -1;
            break;
        } else if(msgbuf.event == ALARM_EVENT_QUIT){
            printf("Recieved Quit event\n");
            break;
        } else if(IsRestart()){
            // If already restart flag is set then ignore the messages
            continue;
        } else {
            /* Process alarm event */
            pEvironment =  (AlarmParam_t*)malloc(sizeof(AlarmParam_t));
            if(pEvironment == NULL){
                printf("Error: More memory need for Alarm server\n");
                break;
            }
            pEvironment -> msg_id    = qid;
            pEvironment -> audMsg_id = audQid;
            pEvironment->hAlarmSem   = hAlarmSem;
            memcpy(&pEvironment -> msg_buf, &msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
            pthread_attr_init(&attr);
            pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED); 
            if((ret = pthread_create(&thread, &attr, ProcAlarmThread,pEvironment)) != 0){
                free(pEvironment);
                printf("Error: Alarm server creat thread fail with error no %d\n", ret);
                break;
            }
            pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
            pthread_detach(thread);
        }
    }
    DestroySem(hGIOSem);
    return ret;
}
```

`alarm_main_loop()` is called inside a thread. This function continuously checks if a msg is received and corresponding action are taken.

After running continuously for almost 2 days we are getting this issue.

Could anyone suggest me what is the reason behind this?

How can we debug this issue?

We tried `pthread_join` instead of `pthread_detach`(without any attributes) but still got the same issue.

Comment: Please include a complete program that exhibits the problem.  Refer to the guidelines listed here [mcve]

Comment: Besides your code gives a very limited picture, I may assume you are facing an interference of another errors occurred before `pthread_create` is called. Reason - your coding style gives an impressions that you don't test errors.

Comment: And another hint: https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create says: EAGAIN - Insufficient resources to create another thread, or a system-imposed limit on the number of threads was encountered.

Comment: @sigjuice I have added the complete code. We are  creating the thread inside a function(function is called from a thread). We are continuously checking if a msg is received or not in that function. Based on that threads are created continuously.

Comment: @dmi I have modified the code. We checked the number of threads at the time of issue using "cat /proc/*/status | grep Threads". Its only around 120.

Comment: It depends on the OS and recources consumption; I have experienced a long time ago on some Linux distros limit a bit more than 100 (similary to what you wrote). On FreeBSD and Solaris the limit I could reach was much higher.

Comment: ...just an idea. Perhaps you could re-design your program to have a pool of worker threads to don't start new threads upon a new message?

Comment: @dmi what about reducing the stack size ???? will that be useful???

Comment: I cannot say for sure what kind of limitation you are facing. I would assume it is slightly less stack size relevant. Try to play around `ulimit`, check amount of open file descriptors including sockets and everything which may point to resources consumption. Perhaps then it gives some clue. But in my assumption this is more a question of SW design rather technical limits.

Comment: @dmi when we tried reducing stack size we didn't have problem in the creation of the above mentioned thread. However it resulted in failure of creation of another thread. What can we infer from this???

Comment: As per my assumption you can get rid of dynamic thread creation and use a pool of worker threads which start upon application start and wait for a trigger to run. Then, instead of creating a new thread as per your example, you can just give the trigger to one them to handle received request. This is a kind of a classical design pattern to serve network communication.